# error compile - in linked list in C

Tags: c, linked-list

the code gives me error in compiling and i don't know why
the question is about a policy company but it has nothing to do here 
just to let you understand what am trying to do

i think that the error is in the line "(*h)=temp"

```
typedef struct
{
    char  cmp_name[20];
    int   pol_code;
    float pol_price;
    int   drivers;
    float new_d;
    float old_d;
} POL;

typedef struct node
{
    POL         policy;
    struct node *next;
} NODE;

  void ins(NODE **h,NODE *p)
{
NODE *temp;
temp=(NODE*)malloc(sizeof(NODE));

if(p==NULL)
{
(*h)=temp;
temp->next=NULL;
}
else
{
p->next=temp;
p=p->next;
temp->next=NULL;
}

    printf("\nEnter Company Name: ");
    scanf("%s",temp->policy.cmp_name);
    printf("\nEnter Policy Code: ");
    scanf("%d",temp->policy.pol_code);
    printf("\nEnter Policy Price: ");
    scanf("%f",temp->policy.pol_price);
    printf("\nEnter Number of Drivers: ");
    scanf("%d",temp->policy.drivers);
    printf("\nAddon for a New Driver: ");
    scanf("%f",temp->policy.new_d);
    printf("\nAddon for a Old Driver: ");
    scanf("%f",temp->policy.old_d);

}
```

Comment: note: i didnt paste the whole code .. its not complete but when it comes to the "scanf" the compiler gives me error

Comment: scanf takes a pointer

Comment: also *temp is undefined

Comment: `scanf` takes a pointer. Try `scanf("%s",&(temp->policy.cmp_name));`

Comment: @yaccz `temp` is uninitialised, not undefined

Comment: @simonc afaik, NODE *temp; // declaration; temp = malloc(...) // definition

Comment: @yaccz, even if that's true, `char[]` decays to `char*`.

Comment: What happens if someone enters a 20 (or more) characters name?

Comment: @StoryTeller you are right, I haven't noticed the [20].

Comment: @isemi sigsegv happens

Comment: I think we can all agree that accepting input from a stream is more involved than simply `fscanf`-ing it. But that is for our apprentice friend to find out on their own ;)

Comment: @user2422824, so the code before the update had nothing to do with your problem? Also, how did you come to the conclusion that the error is at `(*h)=`

Comment: its ok thanks i think now i fixed it .. thank u guys .. it was malloc .. i forgot malloc haha

Answer (score 7):

```
NODE *temp; // This variable is uninitialized. It "points" to a region you haven't allocated.
```

And then you dereference it here:

```
scanf("%s",temp->policy.cmp_name);
```